# [FireDAC ][Phys] [PG] -315. Cannot get vendor library entry point[s]

Tags: postgresql, delphi, conexão, firedac, embarcadero

Olá, estou começando a usar o RAD Community Edition na versão 10.4 e estou tendo um problema na hora de conectar com o database usando o elemento FireDAC Connection.

O DBMS que estou usando é Postgre v9.6 com o pgAdmin 4.

Antes quando eu tentava conectar dava o erro:  Delhpi não pode carregar libpq.dll (o código acho que era 314). Eu encontrei este arquivo na pasta /bin do Postgre v9.6 e aparentemente consegui resolver o problema colocando ele na pasta do executável da minha aplicação e na pasta listada na PATH environment variable .

Agora quando tento me contectar ao DB o erro é o seguinte:
**[FireDAC ][Phys] [PG] -315. Cannot get vendor library entry point[s].
[
PQparameterStatus
PQtransactionStatus
PQsetClientEncoding
pg_encoding_tochar
PQexecPrepared
PQresultErrorField
PQftable
PQftablecol
PQfformat
PQsetNoticeReceiver
PQputCopyData
PQputCopyEnd
PQgetCopyData
PQfreemem
PQencryptPassword
].**

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço muito.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Você preencheu corretamente todos os campos solicitados pelo FireDAC Connection?

Não uso o firedac, mas sei que dando 2 cliques nele vai aparecer uma tela para preencher uns dados, tipo endereço do banco e endereço das libs...

Dá uma olhada nessa página do wiki da Embarcadeiro, pode ajudar

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Connect_to_PostgreSQL_(FireDAC)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sim, preenchi os campos seguindo as recomendações da página mas continua dando erro. Você sabe se tem outro modo de se conectar com o Postgre?

Comment: Tu sabe se dá para usar o postgre na comunity edition com firedac?? as vezes não tem suporte para a forma como tu tá fazendo e tal, tanto que aqui onde trabalho usamos o zeoslib, mas temos a versão do professional  do delphi que não permite usar o firedac em server.

Comment: Sim, eu consegui resolvi o erro. Eu tinha adicionado algumas dlls nas pastas System32 e SysWOW64 sem conferir se eram x86 ou x64.... foi burrice minha mesmo.
Mas mesmo assim, agradeço a sua disponibilidade

Comment: Marca. como resolvido colega.